# How setState with arrow function to change objects which are not in an Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanna do the following:

Change object values from the object below into new stuff.

```
newClass: {
      classTime: {
        hour: "",
        minutes: ""
      },
```

My complete set of code is presented below:

- As you can see, I have `hour` and `minutes` showing in the `timeArray` object, exactly as on the `newClass` object.

So I guess that using a `setState({hour: 'newData'})` could lead to an issue as this object key is not uniquely showing in my `state`.

Also, I would like to understand if this would be the case of using `setState` with an `=>` function. I literally want to keep mutating this state, as I will pass it up using a `callback function` so I can add the info in `newClass` into an array of objects. This means that `newClass` would be a object meant to transit info up to my `parent` `component`.

Anyways, I still have some doubts regarding the use of `setState` along with `prevState`, and using it on `arrow function` syntax.

the complete code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/stoic-jang-3sofl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

and what we are looking at here is on the `fromTwoWayBindingToNewObj` `function`

```
import React from "react";
import TimePicker from "react-time-picker";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    time: "0:00",
    timeArray: [{ className: "whatever", time: { hour: 10, minutes: 15 } }],
    newClass: {
      classTime: {
        hour: "",
        minutes: ""
      },
      instructor: "Kasturi"
    }
  };

  onChangeTimeHandler = time => {
    this.setState({ time });
  };

  pushTimeHandler = () => {
    //gets the time from the TimePicker State
    let time = this.state.time;
    const [hour, minutes] = time.split(":").map(Number);
    const obj = { hour, minutes };
    this.setState(({ timeArray }) => ({
      timeArray: [...timeArray, { hour: obj.hour, minutes: obj.minutes }]
    }));
  };

  //this is the function that I am trying to implement with setState
  fromTwoWayBindingToNewObj = () => {
    let time = this.state.time;
    const [hour, minutes] = time.split(":").map(Number);
    const obj = { hour, minutes };
    this.setState(({ classTime }) => ({
      ClassTIme: { hour: obj.hour, minutes: obj.minutes }
    }));
  };

  render() {
    let arrayOfTime = [...this.state.timeArray];
    let render =
      arrayOfTime.length > 0
        ? arrayOfTime.map((time, index) => (
            <p key={time[index]}>
              hour:{time.hour} minute:{time.minutes}
            </p>
          ))
        : null;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <TimePicker
          onChange={this.onChangeTimeHandler}
          value={this.state.time}
        />
        <h2>Time Displayed Below</h2>
        <p>{this.state.time}</p>
        <hr />
        <h2>Temporary Objec New Class Display</h2>
        <p>
          CLass Time: Hour: {this.state.newClass.classTime.hour} Minutes:
          {this.state.newClass.classTime.minutes}
        </p>
        <button onClick={this.fromTwoWayBindingToNewObj}>
          Update Temp Obj
        </button>
        <hr />
        <h2>The Array of time below</h2>
        <p>{render}</p>
        <button onClick={this.pushTimeHandler}>Push New Time</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  this.setState(({ classTime }) => ({
    ClassTIme: { hour: obj.hour, minutes: obj.minutes }
  }));
```

`ClassTIme` isn't correct as this doesn't exist on your state and the `{ classTime }` wasn't being used.  On your State, you have `newClass: { classTime: }` and your render return was trying to access these properties `CLass Time: Hour: {this.state.newClass.classTime.hour} Minutes:`.

I think you are trying to return:

```js
return {
    newClass: {
        classTime: {
            hour: obj.hour,
            minutes: obj.minutes
        }
    }
}
```

---

You are right, and you can use the callback parameter from setState to make it easier `prevState`. I'm going to help by breaking down, step by step.

1. Moved your logic into the setState, and changed the arrow-function so it uses a block body, so it needs to use a `return`.

```js
  fromTwoWayBindingToNewObj = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      let time = prevState.time;
      const [hour, minutes] = time.split(":").map(Number);
      const obj = { hour, minutes };

      return {
        newClass: {
          classTime: {
            hour: obj.hour,
            minutes: obj.minutes
          }
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

2. Simplied your logic with [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). You only use time from the state.

```js
  fromTwoWayBindingToNewObj = () => {
    this.setState(({time}) => {
      const [hour, minutes] = time.split(":").map(Number);
      const obj = { hour, minutes };

      return {
        newClass: {
          classTime: {
            hour: obj.hour,
            minutes: obj.minutes
          }
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

3. Using [Shorthand Property Names](https://tylermcginnis.com/shorthand-properties/) we can get rid of using `obj.hour`.

```js
  fromTwoWayBindingToNewObj = () => {
    this.setState(({ time }) => {
      const [hour, minutes] = time.split(":").map(Number);
      return { newClass: { classTime: { hour, minutes } } };
    });
  };
```

Comment: I have no words to thank you for sparing some time to give me this lesson! I now understand much much more about setState syntax! I just would like to understand one part of this syntax a little deeper, if you may explain me please.```1- ``` When you change the syntax and use the previous state like this, what it is wrapped like this?```2- ``` ```({time})``` stands for ```prevState.time```? ```3- ``` Why it is not just written without ```({ })```, as a regular function argument?

Comment: That's no problem! `prevState` will be the same shape as `state` so you are correct `time` will be the same value as `prevState.time`.  I can't write `this.setState(({ time }) => {` as `this.setState(time => {` is because `time` parameter is the name of the first parameter in the function. `this.setState(prevState => {` is the same as `this.setState(random => {` the name of the parameter has no meaning, it will be the previous state.  So `random.time` would be your time.

Comment: I made [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-field-k322o?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) which I hope makes it clearer